How to override the compiler used as host compiler in crosstool-ng?
I have Ubuntu installed with multiple gcc versions.
The multiple versions are handled by e.g. having a default gcc, which then symlinks to a gcc-....
So the various gcc versions are all called gcc-....
How can I tell ct-ng not to use the default gcc, but gcc-13?
I tried to find a menu option, but unfortunately "only" found ways to give extra arguments to gcc.
